# Obtener la fecha de creación de una imagen

Tags: php, html

He estado buscando la manera de poder conseguir la fecha de creación de una imagen, es decir, obtener la fecha y hora que fue creada la imagen y no encuentro nada relacionado en la web.

Supongamos que tengo un formulario, el cual tiene diversos `inputs` y entre ellos un `input file`, el cual me permite subir una imagen y almacenar su ruta en la base de datos.

Sin embargo, ¿Cómo puedo obtener la fecha y hora en que la imagen se creo?

OJO: No la fecha / hora en que se subio desde el formulario, si no desde que se tomo la imagen de la cámara.

¿Hay alguna forma de poder obtener ese dato?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? no estoy familiarizado con PHP, pero en C# puedes consultar los detalles de la imagen `desde el lado servidor-backend`. Tambien revisa [exif_read_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) sugerida en esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30802827/4092887).

Comment: @Mauricio Solamente he creado el formulario. No he intentado más por que no se que función debería de usar. Leere más acerca de esa función que dices.

Comment: comprendo, espero haya sido de ayuda y recuerda actualizar tu pregunta con los avances que hayas podido obtener. Espero que mas usuarios te puedan ayudar. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `#filectime` puedes obtener la fecha de creación en Windows o la fecha de modificación en SO basados en UNIX. Esta función retornará la fecha en formato `timestamp`. Luego puedes formatearla, por ejemplo:

```
$timestamp = filectime('/ruta/a/la/imagen.jpg');
$date = date("d M  Y H:i", $timestamp);
echo $date; // 21 Septiembre 2016 17:07
```

Comment: Acabo de leer la documentación de la función, y dice que regresa la última vez que se modifico el archivo, no cuando se creo. ¿Sabes si esta función me permite saber cuando se creo?

Comment: @Hoose dice así porque el único SO en donde los metadatos almacenan la *fecha de creación* es en Windows. En sistemas basados en UNIX (Linux, OSX) siempre será la fecha de modificación.

Comment: Gani Tienes razón, acabo de hacer la prueba y funciono. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Verdaderamente con la función filectime se obtiene la fecha de la última modificación de un archivo, que no se si es lo que estás buscando

Un ejemplo de uso:

```
$nombre_archivo = 'archivo.txt';
if (file_exists($nombre_archivo)) {
echo "La última modificación de $nombre_archivo fue: " . date("F d Y H:i:s.", filectime($nombre_archivo));
}
```

Puedes darle el formato que quieras por medio de date()

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a tu descripción, la funcion `exif_read_data(ruta_de_la_imagen)` debería serte útil.

Te comparto el enlace a la documentación php sobre la misma, espero puedas resolver. http://php.net/manual/es/function.exif-read-data.php